# Is a website that is not linked anywhere completely hidden?

Tags: webserver, nginx, web-crawler

I want to create a webpage that only me, and another person have access to view.

I don't want to use any authentication on it (username/password, certificates etc).

My question is:
If I serve the website from my own web server, and don't put the content on the root directory on port 80 (ie. mywebsite.com/hidden), is there any way that someone else would be able to find it? From what I read about web crawlers, they only find pages that have links to them. Is there any other attack vector I am not think of? Besides a bruteforce search (mywebsite.com/brute/force/this/path)?

Comment: If this person you want to share the website with, is not within your intranet network, anyone on the internet can find it.

Comment: I do this all the time. My main web site www.home.web has a collection of subdirectories, such as www.home.web/private and www.home.web/media, which are not referenced in any of the main site pages, and are accessible only to people that I tell about the addresses. A brute force method might find them, but it would not be used unless there was a reason to think they were there. These hidden directories have never been found, but if they were I would simply change the subdirectory names. The main vulnerability is if traffic to my site were monitored, in which case the addresses would be seen.

Comment: @Ramhound how is it possible someone else could find it?

Comment: There are many known and unknown methods of tracking "hidden" websites.  One method is browser addons, which can see just about everything you do.  If you dont want people to find it, do not put it on the internet unsecured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that a web indexer's (like Google's) primary method of page discovery is via crawling links. However, there are other methods of finding websites.

For instance, Google has its own DNS services which can help it discover new sites in two ways:

1. If you register your domain directly with Google, they would
   certainly know about the new website.
2. Registering the domain at all requires public propagation, so Google would 
   eventually receive the new entry.

Obviously, if you also *host* the site on an indexer's servers, they *could* try crawling your entire site.

But it doesn't sound like you're doing either of these things. If all you're trying to protect is the single page/directory (rather than the entire domain/server), you're not hosting it on an indexer's services, and you're not registering a domain for your hidden path, your primary concern would be to ensure that directory indexing isn't possible on your site.

For instance, with Apache, you can accomplish this by either including a .htaccess file in your root directory with `Options -Indexes` or by removing the `Indexes` directive in the site configuration itself:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/site">
    Options Indexes OtherOptions
</Directory>
```

becomes

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/site">
    Options OtherOptions
</Directory>
```

Alternatively, ensure that you at least have a placeholder index.html file in each folder for the server to serve up, rather than the directory index.

Answer (score 0):

Add a sha256 as the pathname, then you should be fine. Keep track on the logfiles.